# File images display in Dreamweaver CS5 preview window but not from the server

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

[enter link description here](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/stickFigure.htm)[enter link description here](http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/iRockChapter3.htm)This is a javascript project that was created in Dreamweaver CS5 on a Mac in which if else statements are used to show an alert message along with an accompanying scene image.

I'm baffled why in Dreamweaver the scene images display with the alert message in the preview window but once uploaded to the server only the alt description of the image shows.

My document and the scene images are inside the root folder. However, when I move the scene images to a subfolder they don't display in Dreamweaver preview anymore. That's why I keep them in the same root folder.

I was told to make a subfolder for the images but that doesn't work for me. Yet, I looked at some other student's redo of the same homework that was uploaded to the server and their scenes display. What am I doing wrong. Any suggestions.

Comment: Post a link to the page this is on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your img src="" attributes. this page http://ciswebs.smc.edu/cis54/tyson_schweidel/stickFigure.htm  the image doesn't work because it's got a ";" semicolon appended to the img src. remove the semi colon

Comment: Once I removed the ; the code worked. All the scenes displayed with the alert message. Thank you.